# ios push notifications best practices for dev, prod and stage environments

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ios-provisioning

I'm a bit confused with prepping an app for different environments + app store. I have 3 environments- dev, prod and stage and it looks like for a given appId, we get dev and distribution (prod).

Should I use the ad-hoc distribution profile for the staging env, and the app store version for prod? I assume with 3 different profiles, I can run 3 different versions of the app on a single phone?

Or, should I just use 3 different appIds so I can debug all versions of the app, and just keep a distribution profile for the prod version of the app?

EDIT: Re push notifications- would all 3 versions of the app be able to receive notifications while on the same phone?

Answer (score 1):

I created three different version of my app: dev.[App], qa.[App] and [App]. Each needs it's own profile, but they all used the same App ID. I also needed three SSL certs.

---

The token is different for each version of my app, so APS sees them as three separate entities.