# How to send APNS push notifications from Dev, Test, Staging, and Prod environments?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an app with [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) and the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin.  The backend sends push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).  How can I build different flavors of the app which can receive push notifications only from their corresponding flavors of backend?

- Dev (one for each engineer)
- Test
- Staging
- Prod

**Android**: After much searching, I came to the conclusion that FCM access control granularity is per-project.  Therefore, this should work:

1. Create a Firebase project for each flavor.
2. Add a single "Android App" with a unique package name `com.company.app.flavor` to each Firebase project.
3. [Configure build.gradle](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de#2e2d) with the flavors and appropriate `applicationIdSuffix` values so the app binaries end up with the same package names as the Firebase project "Android App" entries.

**iOS**: How to accomplish the same thing for iOS with APNS?

- I found an [answer from 7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792212) that doesn't make sense now.
- Can I follow the same strategy with iOS as with Android, building the app with a unique Bundle-ID for each flavor?  Would that require an app entry in App Store Connect for each of the Bundle-IDs?
- There is [an article on iOS flavors](https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36) but it is missing some information and makes no mention of setting a bundle-id or bundle-id-suffix.

Comment: I encountered an issue with flavors and the certificates for iOS which resulted in i had the same bundle id registered in the different databases. I followed the article you have stumbled upon, but I had to sacrifice the bundle-id-suffix, but otherwise it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "I had the same bundle id registered in the different databases"?  What databases?  And can you please explain what you mean by "I had to sacrifice the bundle-id-suffix"?

Comment: I did not have a unique bundle id for each Firestore database. I had the same bundle id registered in every single one of them. When I compiled the application the build script then included the requested database depending on which flavor I chose. In regards of the sacrifice of the bundle-id-suffix I simple omitted the suffix because I could not make xCode accept the different bundle ids resulting in I could not have multiple version on my iPhone, but the version was properly setup with the matching database.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  My question is about Firebase Cloud Messaging and APNS.  I am not using Firestore databases.

Comment: I utilised the FCM plugin along with Firebase, my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I found, implemented, and tested the solution: Use separate bundle IDs, just like with Android.  For example: `com.company.appname.dev` and com.company.appname.prod`.

The blog post [Flavoring Flutter by Salvatore Giordano](https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36) explains how to set up XCode schemes for each flavor.  The article is useful even if you're not using Flutter.

Here are the steps of my test:

1. Created Firebase project: `appname-dev`

   - Android app: `com.company.app.dev`
   - iOS app: `com.company.app.dev`
   - APNS key: <team key>
2. Created another Firebase Project: `appname-prod`

   - Android app: `com.company.app.prod`
   - iOS app: `com.company.app.prod`
   - APNS key: <same team key>
3. Created the dev flavor of the iOS app, using bundle id `com.company.app.dev` and an icon showing 'dev'.
4. Created the prod flavor of the iOS app, using bundle id `com.company.app.prod` and an icon showing 'prod'.
5. Installed both flavors of the app on my phone.  Launched them and ensured that each initialized the Firebase Cloud Messaging code and asked for permission to show notifications.
6. Used the Firebase Console to send test messages to both apps.
7. Deleted the dev app from my phone.
8. Used the Firebase Console to send test messages to both apps.  Confirmed that only the prod app's message appeared in the phone's lock screen.  The dev app's message did not appear.  This confirms that APNS properly separates the app's dev and prod flavors.